# What is the proper air strip closure procedure with the FAA?

Tags: usa, faa

I own a grass airstrip that was registered for me by a good friend.  I want to sell my land and the guy that registered it is dying and can't help me.  What do I need to do to have this airstrip closed?

Comment: For what it's worth, the usual way in my part of the country (Oregon) for land owners to physically inform pilots that an airstrip is closed is to use plastic sheeting to form a big X's on the ground. The FAA document at http://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/150_5340_1k_consolidated.pdf in section 5.6 gives detail and a graphic in figure 25 near the very end.

Answer (score 28):

It looks to me like you need to file [FAA Form 7480-1](http://aeronav.faa.gov/content/aeronav/Form7480_1.pdf), Notice of Landing Area Proposal.  There is a checkbox for "Deactivation or Abandonment".

The form explains that you have to give 90 days advance notice.  So you shouldn't make any changes until 90 days after filing the form.  This presumably gives them time to update charts, so that pilots know the airstrip is no longer usable.

The form has the address and phone number for your FAA regional office, who might be able to help if you have questions about how to complete the form.